# CBV CreateView influences rendering of UpdateView

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I have a model Anlieferung for which there are two forms a CreateView and a UpdateView. CreateView and UpdateView use either one of the forms, depending on the user.

The problem is that whenever the CreateView is called, all following GET requests to the UpdateView render one information wrongly, i.e. the value rendered in the field "Spedition" is not the same value as in the database. The value rendered in the field "Spedition" is the value of the lastly created "Anlieferung"."spedition" and not the value of the called record.

Restarting the server solves this, either by touching the wsgi.py script or by restarting Apache itself, but this cannot be the solution.

The configuration setup used is Apache with mod_wsgi or the runserver development environment.

models.py:

```
class Anlieferung(models.Model):
    spedition = models.ForeignKey(Spedition, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ankunftszeit = models.TimeField(null=False, blank=False, )
    fahrzeug = models.ForeignKey(Fahrzeug, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    anhaenger = models.ForeignKey(Fahrzeug, related_name='anhaenger', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    anzahlStellplaetze = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False,
                                             verbose_name="Anzahl Stellplätze")
    standort = models.ForeignKey(Standort, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lieferant = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True,
                                 verbose_name="Lieferant / Kundenname")
    SpeditionsAuftrag = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True,
                                         verbose_name="Speditions Auftragsnummer")
    KundenAuftrag = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True,
                                     verbose_name = "Produzenten- oder Kundenauftragsnummer, "
                                                    "Ordernummer oder Bestellnummer")
    leergut = models.ForeignKey(Leergut, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    leergut_anzahl = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Anzahl Leergüter")
    TSAvisierung = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False, auto_now_add=True)
    TSAnmeldung = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=False, verbose_name="Anmeldezeit")
    TSRampenzuordnung = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Zeitstempel Rampenzuordung")
    TSVerladen = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Zeitstempel Verladung abgeschlossen")
    bemerkung = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    temperaturgefuehrt = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='temperaturgeführt')
    entladungstyp = models.ForeignKey(EntladungsTyp, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                      verbose_name="Entladungsart")

    def __str__(self):
        return "Anlieferung:#{}:{}".format(self.kruid, self.ladedatum)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Anlieferung"
        verbose_name_plural = "Anlieferungen"
        ordering = ['-id', ]
```

forms.py

```
class AnlieferungForm(forms.ModelForm):

    removed_documents = forms.CharField(required=False)
    ladedatum = forms.DateField(required=True,
                                help_text='Erfassung muss spätestens bis 16:00h für eine Anlieferung am Folgetag erfolgen.',
                                widget=DateInput())

    def clean_ladedatum(self):
        ladedatum = self.cleaned_data['ladedatum']
        today = datetime.today().date()
        aware = tz.now()
        now = tz.make_naive(aware)
        tomorrow = today + timedelta(days=1)
        if ladedatum <= today:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Das Datum muss in der Zukunft sein.")
        if ladedatum == tomorrow:
            if now.hour > 15:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Anmeldungen für morgen müssen vor 16:00h erfasst werden.")
        return ladedatum

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        logger.debug("AnlieferungForm.__init__called: setzte spedition auf disabled")
        self.fields['spedition'].disabled = True

    class Meta:
        model = Anlieferung
        fields = ['spedition', 'ladedatum', 'fahrzeug', 'anhaenger', 'ankunftszeit', 'lieferant',
                  'KundenAuftrag', 'standort', 'anzahlStellplaetze',
                  'temperaturgefuehrt', 'entladungstyp', 'bemerkung',
                  ]
        widgets = {
                'fahrzeug': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='hp:fahrzeug-autocomplete', forward=['spedition'], ),
                'anhaenger': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='hp:fahrzeug-autocomplete', forward=['spedition'], ),
                'ladedatum': DateInput(),
                'ankunftszeit': TimeInput(),
                }

class AnlieferungMandantForm(forms.ModelForm):
    removed_documents = forms.CharField(required=False)
    ladedatum = forms.DateField(required=True, help_text='Anlieferungen für morgen müssen heute vor 16:00 erfasst werden.',
                                widget=DateInput())

    class Meta:
        model = Anlieferung
        fields = ['spedition', 'fahrzeug', 'anhaenger', 'ankunftszeit', 'lieferant',
                  'KundenAuftrag', 'standort', 'anzahlStellplaetze', 'ladedatum',
                  'temperaturgefuehrt', 'entladungstyp', 'bemerkung',
                  ]
        widgets = {
            'fahrzeug': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='hp:fahrzeug-autocomplete', forward=['spedition'], ),
            'anhaenger': autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='hp:fahrzeug-autocomplete', forward=['spedition'], ),
            'ladedatum': DateInput(),
            'ankunftszeit': TimeInput(),
        }
```

views.py

```
@method_decorator(permission_required('hp.add_anlieferung', raise_exception=True), 'dispatch')
class SpeditionAnlieferungCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Anlieferung
    success_url = reverse_lazy('hp:spedition:anlieferung:index')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['successurl'] = self.success_url
        logger.debug("SpeditionAnlieferungCreateView.get_context_data:context={}".format(context))
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        logger.debug("SpeditionAnlieferungCreateView.form_valid aufgerufen mit form={}".format(form))
        if form.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

    def get_initial(self):
        self.initial.update({
            'spedition': self.request.user.spedition_id,
        })
        return super().get_initial()

    def get_form_class(self):
        if self.request.user.spedition.id == settings.SPEDITION_ID:
            logger.debug("SpeditionAnlieferungCreateView.get_form_class: Benutzer {} ist Speditionsbenutzer.".format(self.request.user))
            return AnlieferungMandantForm
        else:
            logger.debug("SpeditionAnlieferungCreateView.get_form_class: Benutzer {} ist externe Spedition.".format(self.request.user))
            return AnlieferungForm

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_staff:
            # Systemadministratoren sollen alles sehen
            logger.debug("SpeditionAnlieferungCreateView.get_queryset: is_staff")
            return Anlieferung.objects.all()
        else:
            # Sicherheit, falls Spedition nicht gesetzt, dann Mandant voraussetzen
            if self.request.user.spedition_id is None:
                logger.debug("SpeditionAnlieferungCreateView.get_queryset: Benutzer hat keine Spedition gesetzt.")
                return Anlieferung.objects.filter(spedition_id=settings.SPEDITION_ID)
            else:
                if self.request.user.spedition_id == settings.SPEDITION_ID:
                    # Mandant darf alles sehen
                    logger.debug("SpeditionAnlieferungCreateView.get_queryset: Benutzer ist Mandant.")
                    return Anlieferung.objects.all()
                else:
                    # externe Spedition darf nur seine Anlieferungen sehen
                    logger.debug("SpeditionAnlieferungCreateView.get_queryset: Benutzer ist externe Spedition.")
                    return Anlieferung.objects.filter(spedition_id=self.request.user.spedition_id)


@method_decorator(permission_required('hp.change_anlieferung', raise_exception=True), 'dispatch')
class SpeditionAnlieferungUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Anlieferung
    success_url = reverse_lazy('hp:spedition:anlieferung:index')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['successurl'] = self.success_url
        logger.debug("SpeditionAnlieferungUpdateView.get_context_data:context={}".format(context))
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        logger.debug("SpeditionAnlieferungUpdateView.form_valid aufgerufen mit form={}".format(form))
        if form.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

    def get_form_class(self):
        if self.request.user.spedition.id == settings.SPEDITION_ID:
            logger.debug("SpeditionAnlieferungUpdateView.get_form_class: Benutzer {} ist Speditionsbenutzer.".format(self.request.user))
            return AnlieferungMandantForm
        else:
            logger.debug("SpeditionAnlieferungUpdateView.get_form_class: Benutzer {} ist externe Spedition.".format(self.request.user))
            return AnlieferungForm

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.user.is_staff:
            # Systemadministratoren sollen alles sehen
            logger.debug("SpeditionAnlieferungUpdateView.get_queryset: is_staff")
            return Anlieferung.objects.all()
        else:
            # Sicherheit, falls Spedition nicht gesetzt, dann Mandant voraussetzen
            if self.request.user.spedition_id is None:
                logger.debug("SpeditionAnlieferungUpdateView.get_queryset: Benutzer hat keine Spedition gesetzt.")
                return Anlieferung.objects.filter(spedition_id=settings.SPEDITION_ID)
            else:
                if self.request.user.spedition_id == settings.SPEDITION_ID:
                    # Mandant darf alles sehen
                    logger.debug("SpeditionAnlieferungUpdateView.get_queryset: Benutzer ist Mandant.")
                    return Anlieferung.objects.all()
                else:
                    # externe Spedition darf nur seine Anlieferungen sehen
                    logger.debug("SpeditionAnlieferungUpdateView.get_queryset: Benutzer ist externe Spedition.")
                    return Anlieferung.objects.filter(spedition_id=self.request.user.spedition_id)
```

My first idea was, that there were corrupt .pyc - files and I deleted and restarted the server -> this did not solve the problem and after another created Anlieferung, the rendering in the AnlieferungUpdateView agains delivers the wrong value.

I wrote selenium browser tests to verify behavior and it is reproducible and most probably linked to the CreateView or UpdateView itself. I debugged the Django MRO calls of the get_context_data() and found that for an unknown reason in FormMixin the initial - value is filled with the wrong value. It should be empty all the time, but as explained after another record has been saved, it initializes with the wrong value - I have no further clue where this does come from.

Nevertheless, I cannot imagine how a call to a certain view influences one value of another view. I'm running out of ideas... Any help is highly appreciated.